# Punching Diablo?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

One of the Diablo 3 achievements simply says "Punch Diablo."

How exactly does one achieve this? Is it a matter of removing all weapons, or is it a class/skill-based feat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar to [The Hero's New Clothes achievement](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/the-heros-new-clothes), you literally have to unequip your weapon(s) and attack Diablo with your fists. You'll need to remove your Primary attack ability from the A button and have that slot empty.

Comment: A strangely downvoted answer makes the point that you don't need to change your ability bar choice, simply spam an ability that is a resource *spender* until the resource runs out, then it will "fail" and do a plain vanilla attack instead.  Done.

Answer (score 19):

Easily done, unequip your weapons, get close to diablo and quickly swap your primary attack ability, so it enters in cooldown and you'll be able to punch him when attacking, by doing this, you'll instantly get the achievement, no matter if you die after that. i just got it now: 09:40a.m 16/05/2012 (-3:00 GMT)

Comment: Thanks for actually telling how one attacks with a basic auto-attack.

Comment: This is the important bit. I tried just unequipping, no dice.

Answer (score 9):

Remove your weapons and your Secondary skill (either drag it off the toolbar, or go equip your secondary skill somewhere else and it will change to an auto-attack), and hit him with your right-mouse button (secondary).

As a helpful tip to avoid dying, when Diablo gets to really low hp (not sure of the exact %, but its less than 5%) in the final fight, he will stop attacking and simply sits there.

This gives you plenty of time to remove your weapons and skills without risking dying, and to punch him

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this on the system, PS4 for example. Take your character, I used the Barbarian. I removed my sword and shield (while in the equip menu push R3). I then went to the skill menu and cleared my "X" button skill by entering it and hitting the "Triangle" button. I then loaded the last checkpoint of Act IV and walked up and hit Diablo with the "X" button. Challenged complete.

Answer (score -1):

Attack with no weapon or resource = punch. You don't have to switch attacks...I did it with whirlwind on my barb.  When he ran out of fury, he punched, then cha-ching!

Comment: I "accidentally" got this as well. HC Crusader, ran out of wrath.
Dunno why all the down-votes... bloody haters.

Comment: You're saying unequip your weapons, select an ability which is a resource *spender*, and spam it until you run out of resources, at which point it stops working and your attack becomes a simple attach (punch since you have no weap equipped).  **Superb.**